# Design question: how to implement a function which utilizes different interface implementations

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-mvc

I'm working on a quite big Web-Application as of late and I am unfamiliar with the underlying concepts.

So my question is:

**TASK:**

- delete all data gathered by a user (settings, userdata (username & password) and bowling stats (games, shot series and single shot data))

  - username and password,
  - Settings set by user
  - stats about bowling like games, shot series, single shot

**Existing implemented code so far:**

- Interface *UsersService.kt*, implemented in *UsersServiceImpl.kt*
- Interface *ShotsService.kt*, implemented in *ShotServiceImpl.kt*
- Interface *SettingsService.kt*, implemented in *SettingsService.kt*

**Reference to given task:**

I want to extend the logic of the implementation of the delete-function in *UsersServiceImpl.kt*, so that in this case when this function is called, it does not only delete the corresponding username and password, but settings and player stats first.

Is the correct way to do this to call the implementations of the other interfaces inside the UsersServiceImpl.delete()-function?

```
 override fun delete(userId: UserId) {
    // my additional code
    shotServiceImpl.deleteShots(userID)
    shotServiceImpl.deleteSeries(userID)
    shotServiceImpl.deleteMatches(userID)
    settingsServiceImpl.deleteSettings(userID)

    // previously only this following two lines existed.
    usersRepository.deleteById(userId)
    userSecretsRepository.deleteById(userId)

}
```

Or is there another way which is recommended to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the concerns separated. The `delete` function in the `UsersService` should do one thing: deleting users.

Deleting all user related settings is part of a higher policy. You could implement a service that knows all interfaces and executes their corresponding delete functions in the correct order.

I would also advice you to look at other locations of the code base to figure out if specific design patterns for those kind of tasks are used already.

Comment: Probably stupid question, but I'm kinda stuck. So if I implement a Service which knows the interfaces this new Service also needs to implement those completely, doesn't it? Can you clarify it a bit? :)

Comment: By 'knows' I mean that the new service has references to the interfaces. The implementation of those interfaces can be injected or passed in the constructor of the service for instance.